# How do I fix the scale in Chrome to scale the data and not the page?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, scale

I do not have any experience writing code at all. I accidently hit the F12 key and changed something in the code in Chrome dealing with scale. Previously when I would print a page in Chrome that I wanted to shrink the information to fit on one page I could change the scale from default to custom and change the data to fit within the page by reducing the scale number. Now whenever I change the scale to custom and change the scale number it shrinks the page I am viewing in proportion to the page. How do I change the code so when I change the scale to custom it allows me to shrink the data in the print area and not page in proportion to the print area?

I reached out to my IT department and asked them to see if they could fix the scale issue. Three individuals attempted to fix whatever I changed with no success. Finally, they uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled. That did not fix the scale issue either. They cannot help and I am asking if there is someone in this forum that would be willing to dumb it down for me so I can fix this issue on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue. I don't think this is something you changed, I think this is the result of the latest Chrome update 117.

The only fix I have found is to change the margins to "minimum" or "custom" instead of default when printing. I then had to scale down the % even lower than before (for one webpage I used to scale down to 80%, now I have to scale down to 60)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for that tidbit. That worked and I was able to scale up and down again. Just wanted to let you know that I received another response too and it sounds like an even better fix. Though you might want to check it out. If I can change the setting like suggested, then perhaps I wouldn't have to adjust the margin or custom every time I print. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing print issues after chrome update when before everything was printing correctly. After hours of debugging I found that a `margin-left` styling set to -6em was the issue. I removed that and the print format was fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Where did you find the "margin-left" styling setup? I would to try to make that change and see if I get the same results. I tried what Jonathan recommended with the margin change and that allowed me to scale the page again. However this sounds like it might be a better fix, and I would not have to alter the margins or custom each time I print.

Comment: I was generating the html, I just removed that styling from one of the tag elements.